# How to size an in-line fuse for the input of the DC-DC power supply

Tags: power, fuses

I have purchased a [Meanwell switching power](https://www.meanwell-web.com/content/files/pdfs/productPdfs/MW/SD-200/SD-200-spec.pdf) supply with the following specifications:

Input: DC 36-72V (6.7A)

Output: DC 24V (8.4A)

I want to put an inline fuse on the positive cable going to the input of the power supply (V+). The load is around 7.2A. The source is from a 48V forklift battery.

The reason for the inline fuse is to protect against shorting the inputs when connecting power. Should I spec the fuse for the input current of 6.7A and use an 8A fuse or should I spec the input fuse for the output of 8.4A and use a 10A fuse?

Comment: When sizing a fuse, the wire size also needs to be considered. What wire diameter are you using on the input side, between the battery and the power supply? Or if you are not sure, then how long is the wire going to be from battery to supply?

Comment: @mkeith The wire size is a 2.5mm cable that can handle 13.5 A.

Comment: The input (6.7A) is the maximum current it will use, but I would spec the fuse for 15A.

Comment: @BeB00 is 15A not too much of margin? Do you think the 10A blows under a normal power connection?

Comment: My point is more that 15A fuses are fairly standard and easy to find, but also that the exact value doesn't really matter much in your system. Your goal is to stop the wire melting (and other damage) during a short. Your wire definitely wont melt at 15A, and a short is definitely much more than 15A, so you can be sure that the fuse will blow. You can choose any value between 7A and probably 20A+, but you also want to be sure that it wont blow during (for example) inrush to your power supply, or other transient conditions.

Comment: @BeB00 indeed the inrush and transients need to be tested. So I shall do some experiments to see which fuse value is just right. Can you post your comment as an answer so I can close this question, thanks.

Comment: The other answers are more detailed than my comment so you should probably accept one of them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably use a 15 A fuse unless the power supply documentation specifies different information.

The first rule of fuse sizing is to make sure the fuse will blow before the wire overheats. Generally you look up the ampacity of the wire in an ampacity table and then make sure the fuse is smaller than the wire ampacity. In this case the ampacity is somewhere around 20 amps (depending on the table you use).

The second rule is to make the fuse large enough so that it doesn't blow in normal use (nuissance blowing). One thing that could cause a fuse to nuissance blow is short bursts of high current when a battery is connected to a power supply with input capacitors. In your case, the battery has the ability to deliver very high current upon initial connection. So you may get large inrush currents. This is why I have gone to a larger fuse.

The third rule is that the voltage rating of the fuse must be high enough. In your case I guess 48 V is enough, or 60 V if you want to be more conservative.

The fourth rule, most often overlooked is to make sure the fuse is rated to interrupt the largest possible fault current. You might think a 15 A fuse will blow if the current is over 15 A and that is all there is too it. But some 15 A fuses can interrupt fault currents of 10,000 amps or more, whereas others may only be rated for 100 amps. Usually the higher interrupt rating will make the fuse larger and more expensive. But if the interrupt rating is exceeded, the fuse may literally explode under fault conditions, and pieces of it will fly all over. So I think it is worth it for safety. So you probably want to get a fuse that can interrupt at least 1,000 amps, because your battery can probably put out 1,000 amps for a short time.

A lot of marine fuses are designed to interrupt large fault currents in DC battery systems. So those types of fuses may be a good choice.

I did a quick survey and couldn't find any beefy marine fuses for less than 30 A. So I suppose another option would be to put the 30 A heavy-duty fuse (with 1000 A interrupt capability) near the battery and put your wimpy 15 A fuse (with 100 A or so interrupt capability) near the load. If an extreme high current event happens, maybe the 30 A fuse will limit the total energy passed to the 15 A fuse to an acceptable level to prevent catastrophic failure mode. Or just find the highest interrupt rating 15 A fuse you can.

Answer (score 4):

The fuse must be chosen for both the steady state load and initial connection input connection with Meanwell’s spec. of  INRUSH CURRENT (Typ.) 45A/48VDC

The storage caps must be charged up and the I^2t must be measured to choose the appropriate size with ambient temp derating.  Fuses have a very wide tolerance to trip for inrush, and it is not easy to choose a slow-blow.  Too small makes it unreliable for frequent surge operations and too big makes it take a long time if it starts to draw twice it’s rated current.  But the capacitor ESR inside is what often limits that current surge and output ripple, so these are tradeoffs.

This is a 200W output supply that draws a surge peak of  ~ 48V x 45A = 2160 W but how many Joules of energy is stored to provide a high efficiency step down voltage is the key factor which is unknown.

The input current will be max. steady-state for the Vmin input which 36V * 6.7A = 242 W with Imax output of 200W indicating 80% efficient a Vmin.  Your efficiency ought be better at 48V , perhaps 85%.

- a [slo-blow fuse](https://belfuse.com/resources/datasheets/circuitprotection/ds-cp-5st-5stp-series.pdf) at twice the rating takes about 2 minutes to fuse at room temp.
- an 8A time-delay fuse might be able to survive the exponentially decaying surge because it might take 100ms at 45 A to trip and the current at this time will be well below.
- I suspect if the Joules of surge energy was known, and the fuse withstanding time delay energy was known, it could be a simple calculation to choose a safety margin.
- In the end, I suspect an 8A to 10A fuse will blow before the battery or cable but not trip from the surge energy to start.
- There may be clever ways to soft start if Meanwell agrees it won’t overheat any internal components